# ES6 String templating litterals : dealing with array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use the ES6 String template to query my database

My SQL is like :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ();
```

The in must contains each items of an array, so, i tried something like this :

```
return connector.query`SELECT * FROM table WHERE AnalogHistory.TagName IN (${sensor})`.then(result => {return result.recordset});
```

This doesn't work. But if i try something like this :

```
return connector.query`SELECT * FROM table WHERE AnalogHistory.TagName IN (${sensor[0]},${sensor[1]}, ${sensor[2]}, ...)`.then(result => {return result.recordset});
```

Well this time, it work. So do you guys know what differ and on to do it by the first way (the cleaner) ?

Comment: What is this `connector.query`, and is it actually written as a tag function? If so, how does it handle the tag parameters? We can't really answer without knowing that.

Comment: They aren't "string templates," they're template literals. On their own, they generate a string; but when you use them with a tag function (as you appear to be), they may well not.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what you want to do, but would `${sensor.join(",")}` suit your needs? It converts every item in the array to a string and then connects those strings with a `,` essentially doing what you did in your second example.

Comment: @KhauriMcClain: In the second example, the OP **didn't** assume the entries in `sensor` were strings. The entries will be passed to the tag function intact, not as strings. What happens then depends entirely on what the tag function does. The question doesn't tell us enough to know whether we could convert those entries to strings and directly include them in an `IN` clause without causing an SQL syntax error or SQL injection opportunity.

Comment: @Littlesquirrel: Stack Overflow is a **very** active place. When you post a question (or answer), *stick around* for a while so you can respond to comments asking for clarification.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The connector.query is owned by the mssql NPM package. I followed up their documentation, in the ES6 section.

Comment: @KhauriMcClain nice try, but it still doesn't work

Comment: The sensor might be a string, or an array of string. But, i'm able to clone the function to deal with the both

Comment: And what version of it are you using? (Given there are breaking changes between 3 and 4.) What did you see in the documentation about passing arrays as tag parameters?

Comment: i use the version 4. i didn't see in the documentation about passing array, but i supposed it, according to the spy test. Actually `${sensor} ${from} ${to}` gave me "A_000000000000000000000000000021.PV,A_000000000000000000000000000042.PV,A_000000000000000000000000000044.PV,A_000000000000000000000000000045.PV... 2016-08-09T00:00:00Z 2017-08-16T15:29:38Z ". It's like something is missing for sql side, but there is no error

Comment: @Littlesquirrel "gave you" ***where***?

Comment: The question lacks http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It should contain definitions of connector.query and sensor.

Answer (score 0):

We can't be absolutely sure without knowing how `query` handles the tag parameters, but the difference is that in the first case, you've provided `query` with the array as a single parameter; and in the second case, you've provided `query` with a series of individual parameters with commas in-between them.

Apparently it's happy with the second, and not with the first. Whether there's a third option that would be less laborious but also functional depends entirely on how `query` is designed to be called.

---

Re your comment saying it's the `mssql` npm package: I don't see anything in [its documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#es6-tagged-template-literals) to suggest that it supports passing arrays into the `query` tag function as parameters. Which is really unfortunate.